# Secure document storage and message system

Tags: chat, document-management, login

I am searching for a software based solution to enable customers to login into a space in which documents are exclusively stored for them to view and download and that the company is able to communicate 1:1 via chat or messages within this space.

The solution should be SaaS and the data is confidential. So it should be a professional solution. The customers are created by the company itself manually or with a registration form. The upload of the documents is done by the company without any automation. When uploading new documents or new messages are written, the user should be informed via email.

Is there any simple and easy solution on the market which meets these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

ITNOA

If you want large scale enterprise on-premise solution You can use

- Skype For Business [SharePoint 2016 on premise integration with Lync or Skype for business](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/274071)
- OneDrive for Business
- SharePoint Server, for example [How to create a simple file sharing server in SharePoint Server 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/752e1fa8-7909-44fd-8b15-86289cc73381/how-to-create-a-simple-file-sharing-server-in-sharepoint-server-2013-)
- Exchange Server

together, for example see [Plan Exchange 2016 integration with SharePoint and Skype for Business](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/integration-with-sharepoint-and-skype/integration-with-sharepoint-and-skype?view=exchserver-2019)

If you want simple solution and does not need on-premise solution you can easily using Microsoft Teams and SharePoint Online

Comment: Thanks, but I am thinking more in a portal system solution.

Comment: @Tim, with integration between SharePoint and Skype For Bussiness and One Drive For Business, you can create enterprise grade shared storage with strong collaboration fundamental.